# Is there a reason to consider formulas with multiple quantifiers on the same variable?

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

I'm very green at mathematical logic, so I apologize for what may be a stupid question.

As I understand it, the definition of a first-order formula allows for monstrosities like

$$\exists x \neg \exists x \varphi(x),$$

$$\forall x \forall x \forall x \exists x \psi(x),$$

etc.  Is there a good reason to define formulas in such a way that these kinds of "formulas" are included?  For instance, I was trying to write up a proof of the Tarski-Vaught test, and it seems like this case requires special handling apart from the main argument.

My natural instinct would be to define formulas in such a way that $\exists x \phi$ is a formula only if $x$ is a free variable in $\phi$, but this doesn't seem to be how things are generally done.

Comment: `Is there a good reason to define formulas in such a way that these kinds of "formulas" are included?` Is there any good reason not to? And within 'good reason' I certainly don't think human intuition/perception should play a role.

Comment: Well, one good reason not to is that it would cut the length of this proof in half without losing any actual substance, at least assuming that there's no reason anyone would ever consider such a formula for any reason.

Comment: Are you talking about the Tarski-Vaught test specifically? I thought you took it just as an example. I removed the tag *model theory* because of that. If you feel it is appropiate, please add it back again.

Comment: Well, it's the first not-completely-trivial thing I've done.  But I imagine that if you need a special case in *this* proof then you need a special case in *every* proof.  (Also, the proofs of Tarski-Vaught I've seen written down neglect this case, meaning that they're not actually valid unless you use my definition.)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no good reason to consider such formulae, where the quantifiers on the same variable are arranged in a chain having strictly more than one element. However, I think that formulae like $\forall x Px \wedge \forall x(Px \rightarrow Qx) \rightarrow \forall xQx$ where the quantifiers on the same variable form an antichain are quite useful in practice.

Comment: @user18921, a formula like that would still be allowed under the formulation I describe above.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, ah my eye skipped over that bit. Yes, I think the convention you describe is a very sensible one. However I'm not expert, so lets wait for a seasoned veteran to answer.

Comment: In any case I find it hard to believe that the proof is cut short using the definition you propose. A 'mathematical proof'? Maybe. A formal proof? Doubt it.

Comment: Using the definition you propose, $\exists x(0=0)$ isn't a formula.

Comment: @GitGud, I think it would actually shorten a formal proof, given that the actual hypothesis of the test concerns the formula $\exists w. \varphi(\overline{v}, w)$ where $w$ is a free variable.  If $w$ is not a free variable you can't apply the hypothesis directly and have to work around it.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury You're right.

Comment: @GitGud, a good convention would be that $x$ is trivially free in $0=0$, thus $\exists x(0=0)$ is a formula.

Comment: @GitGud, in particular, we would define that $x$ is *free* in $\varphi$ iff $x$ is not bound in $\varphi$, whether or not it appears in $\varphi$.

Comment: @user18921 That seems to work. But I wonder about the repercusions of not being able to freely add quantifiers behind a formula, particularly in the context of [arithmetical hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

Comment: @GitGud, that's a good point I hadn't thought of.

Comment: I guess this is not a big deal in light of the answer below.  It would be nice if this was pointed out in texts directly after the definition of formulas (or of free variables), especially since they seem to want to use it implicitly.

Comment: @user18921: it is common in an argument to write "let $\phi(x,y)$ have exactly the free variables shown". In your convention, every (finite) formula has an infinite set of free variables, which is somewhat odd. The typical definition is that $x$ is free in a formula if it has a "free occurrence", bound if it has a "bound occurence", and some variables are neither free nor bound.

Comment: The proof of the Tarski-Vaught test in Marker's book does not appear to have any special case for this, and I can't see why it would. Remember that, in induction on formulas, you are working from the inside out, not from the outside in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that when a specific variable $x$ is quantified repeatedly, the quantifier nested closest to the quantified statement is the one and only quantifier of $x$ that applies: it negates any and all previous quantifiers on that variable.

So:

$$\exists x, \color{blue}{\lnot \exists x}\varphi(x)\;\equiv\;\lnot \exists x\, \varphi(x)$$

$$\forall x,\,\forall x, \,\forall x, \,\color{blue}{\exists x}\, \psi(x)\; \equiv \;\exists x\, \psi(x)$$

Comment: I see.  I guess this is being implicitly used in a lot of arguments.

Comment: This is just a consequence, by the way, of the definition of the semantics of first-order logic. $(\forall x)\phi$ is true in $M$ if and only if, for each $c\in M$, $\phi(c)$ is true in $M$, where $\phi(c)$ is obtained by replacing each free occurrence of $x$ in $\phi$ with $c$. If $\phi$ has no free occurrences of $x$ then the replacement is vacuous, and in that case $(\forall x)\phi$ is equivalent to $\phi$.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Thanks. I saw immediately that amWhy's statement was true under the definition I had (which is in terms of assignments); I just wouldn't have come up with it without being told.  I see that the convention you describe, where $\phi(c)$ means to replace *free* occurrences, looks like it will solve my immediate problems.  Is this convention written down somewhere?

Comment: @Daniel McLaury: it is written in some books, when the authors are being particularly careful. But I just looked at Marker's book and he avoids the issue with a footnote on page 10, with a reference to Shoenfield's classic book for the general definition of a model satisfying a formula. The key thing to look for is the term "occurence"; authors who just talk about "free variables" are going to have problems with formulas like $Q(x) \land (\forall x) P(x)$. The key point, of course, is that only one occurence of $x$ in that formula is free.

Comment: A book that uses the "other" method is Enderton's *Mathematical Introduction to Logic". This is the method in which one uses variable assignment functions rather than adding parameters to the language for the elements of the model. I often assign it as a sort of exercise for students to figure out how his definition of satisfaction (correctly) handles formulas where the same variable is used for more than one thing.

Comment: Thanks!  The notes I was looking at used assignments, so it wasn't necessary to define what $\phi(c)$ meant in order to define satisfaction.  As a consequence that notation wasn't actually defined anywhere; you were just supposed to intuit what it meant, which was obvious enough in the case where the variables were free.

Comment: The other place this comes up is in certain deductive systems such as typical Hilbert-style systems. These include a deduction rule saying that from $x=y$ and $\phi(x,\ldots)$ you can deduce $\phi(y,\ldots)$ which is obtained by replacing all free occurrences of $x$ in $\phi$ with $y$. These deductive systems can be used even if the semantics is defined in terms of variable assignments.

Comment: Thanks to your answers I became a lover of logic+1

Comment: this is very pedantic, but don't you have to be *slightly* careful if your logic allows for empty structures? in that case, if I'm not mistaken, the sentence $\exists x\forall x (x=x)$ does not hold in the empty structure, even though the sentence $\forall x (x=x)$ does. anyway I guess most formulations of first-order logic do not allow for empty structures, so it's probably a moot point. but perhaps worth pointing out (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few places where the convention is used:

- If $x$ is not free in $\psi$ then $(\forall x)\phi \lor \psi$ is equivalent to $(\forall x)(\phi \lor \psi)$. This is used to help put formulas in prenex normal form. If $\psi$ contains $x$ as a bound variable, under the proposal in the question, we would have to modify the algorithm for prenex form, because otherwise  $(\forall x)(\phi \lor \psi)$ might no longer be a formula. In particular, the algorithm would no longer be purely recursive in the same way.
- If we want to replace a symbol in a formula with its definition in terms of another formula, normally we can ignore any bound quantifiers in the definition. For example, the set-theoretic formula $\emptyset \subseteq x$ can be rewritten in the language $\{\in\}$ as $$(\forall z)[(\forall w)[w \not \in z] \to (\forall p)[p \in z \to p \in x]]$$ 
  If we did this inside a larger formula, we can normally just ignore any outer quantifiers over $z$, $w$, or $p$, because these are not free in the displayed formula above. It would add a small amount of extra work to keep changing the variables to other ones.